# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment - new to Python

Tags: python

Trying to do some some questions in a book yet I'm stuck with my arrays. I get this error:

```
count[i] = x
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

My code:

```
import pylab
count = 0

for i in range (0,6):
    x = 180
    while x < 300:
        count[i] = x
        x = x + 20
        print count
```

Basically I need to use a loop to store values which increase until they hit 300 in an array. I'm not sure why I'm getting that error.

I might have worded this poorly. I need to use a loop to make 6 values, from 200, 220, 240... to 300, and store them in an array.

Comment: `count` is an integer, not a `list`. You need to make `count = []`, and to add things to a `list`, you use `.append`

Answer (score 4):

`count` is an integer. Integers don't have indexes, only lists or tuples (or objects based on them) do.

You want to use a list, and then append values to it:

```
count = []
for i in range (0,6):
    x = 180
    while x < 300:
        count.append(x)
        x = x + 20
        print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `count` as an `int` number and as the error says (`'int' object does not support item assignment`) you need a list instead , :

```
count = []
```

and use `append()` function to append the numbers to your list :

```
for i in range (0,6):
    x = 180
    while x < 300:
        count.append(x)
        x = x + 20
        print count
```

Comment: Doing that, it tells me:count[i] = x
     IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @Versace yes , as you initial your list empty it raise index error , you need to use `append` function

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the while loop, you  can use range with a start,stop,step:

```
count = []
for i in xrange (6):
    for x in  xrange(180,300,20):
        count.append(x)
        print count
```

Or use range with extend:

```
count = []
for i in xrange(6):
    count.extend(range(180,300,20))
```

Or simply:

```
 count range(180,300,20) * 6 `
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary

```
count = {}

for i in range (0,6):
    x = 180
    while x < 300:
        count[i] = x
        x = x + 20
        print count
```